# Is it possible to get the audio files for the TalkBack "earcons"?

Tags: audio, accessibility, talk-back

I'm interested to know whether there are audio files tucked away somewhere for the "earcons" - the sounds that TalkBack makes for certain things, like links, page scrolling, etc. Are these available somewhere/somehow?

Answer (score 2):

Talkback is open source, and the files available on Github:
https://github.com/rmtheis/eyes-free

The audio files are included in the repository in .ogg format. Simply download the repository and extract all of the .ogg files to access the audio.